# Manipulate sealed type in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, extension-methods

I want to, for example, add a method to `integer` (i.e., `Int32`), which will make me able to do the following:

```
int myInt = 32;
myInt.HelloWorld();
```

One can say, instead of insisting doing the above, you can write a method which takes an `integer`, `HelloWorld(integer)`, like the following, more easily:

```
int myInt = 32;
HelloWorld(myInt);
```

However, I'm just curious whether it's possible or not. If true, is that a *good programming practice* to add some other functionality to well known classes?

PS: I tried to make another class which *inherits* from `Int32`, but cannot derive from sealed type 'int'.

Comment: I think you want extension methods

Comment: Though this is possible with extension methods (as others have pointed out), I would suggest that you not do this for fundamental types like 'int'.  This is much less intuitive for a maintenance engineer looking at your code a year from now and wondering what it means for the number 32 to say hello, as opposed to something like World.SayHello(32).  The intuitive sense of an extension method is that the extended object is doing something, but there's very little that a number should be actively doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add an extension method for `int32`.

```
   public static class Int32Extensions
   {
       public static void HelloWorld(this int value) 
       {
         // do something
       }
   }
```

Just remember to `using` the namespace the class is in.

Answer (score 3):

You're after [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).
There is nothing wrong with them OOP speaking because you don't have access to private variables nor alter the behaviour of the object in any way.

Its only syntactic sugar on what you've described exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mention extension method [programming guide of extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Q: Is that a good programming practice to add some other functionality to well known classes?

This type of discussion really belongs on 'Programmers'.

Please take a look at this discussion on Programmers, that has a lot of philosophical points on using extension methods:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/why-arent-extension-methods-being-used-more-extensively-in-net-bcl

Also:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41740/when-to-use-abstract-classes-instead-of-interfaces-and-extension-methods-in-c?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use Extensions methods

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        2.HelloWorld();
    }

    public static void HelloWorld(this int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use extension method
like this:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static string HelloWorld(this int i)
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```